# How can I enter data into database by pressing the button with using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

I'm setting up a project by using python language to take feedback from customers by pressing the button, my question about the code to enter the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
connector = mysql.connector.connect(host="host", user="user", passwd="password", database="DB")
cnx = connector.cursor()
cnx.execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s)", ('data'))
# Or execute a query just as always
#cnx.execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)")
connector.commit()
# If "SELECT * FROM ..." use next line to get the data
#result = cnx.fetchall()
cnx.close()
connector.close()
```